# T-SQL Temp Tables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am trying to debug a stored proc in Visual Studio 2010.  I need to be able to see data in temp tables I created by I do not know how to access that data during debugging.

How do I "dump" the values in a temp table when I am debugging through Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the answer is you can't.  SQL Server doesn't allow you to access the contents of the temp tables when debugging.  Your best bet is to do a `SELECT INTO` to a permanent table and then go from there.  That's the only work-around I can think of.